# Citations from pre-print and academic achievements - should I add them to the accepted article?

Tags: citations, preprint, biorxiv

Should I add citations from the pre-print to the accepted article, when I'm evaluated at the University ? Or should I keep them separate ?

Comment: This depends entirely on your university's rules for this.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo So in general, if University only accepts citations from Web of Science, then those from pre-print mean nothing ?

Comment: I have no idea.  Only those people in your university in charge of interpreting your university's rules can tell you.